# Format numbers using JScript

Tags: javascript, numbers, decimal

I have numbers that I want to add a decimal point before the last 2 digits on the right. For example:

```
 4000000 => 40000.00
 1373917 => 13739.17
 12399 => 123.99
```

I tried to use toFixed, but that returns a string plus it didn't work. Using toFixed still returned for me the same value.
I am working with numbers not strings.

Thanks in advance. Appreciate your help.

Comment: `number / 100` will do what you want

Comment: What you want to do is not formatting. You want to perform computations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope the below helps! Use `toFixed` with `parseFloat`.

```js
console.log((4000000/100).toFixed(2))// 40000.00
console.log((1373917/100).toFixed(2)) //13739.17
console.log((12399/100).toFixed(2)) // 123.99
```